# How to Convert from IDC to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

How can I convert  Internet Data Connector (IDC) to ASP.Net ?
I tried to download  IDC2ASP.EXE from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952612.aspx

But the download link displays an error.

Comment: FYI, I doubt that you want anything to do with "ASP". You mean "ASP.NET"

Answer (score 0):

There is no natural path for moving IDC to asp.net or even IIS 7.  Basically, you just need to start over.

Go here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525831(v=vs.90).aspx